# using cpp preprocessing replaces 0x0D with 0x0A in a string

Tags: linux, sed, makefile, preprocessor

At my workplace we are using an old proprietary language in combination with some C macro's.  In order to compile this code it has to be heavily groomed using a script and I was hoping to move to standardize to an actual makefile.

Right now I am running into an issue in which there are 0x0D (\r) characters in some string definitions in the code which after getting pushed through cpp come out as a 0x0A (\n) and prevent compiling.

I have tried running sed -e 's/\x0A/\x0D/g' but that (along with a large number of permutations) does not seem to have any affect on the output.  Any thoughts on how to address this?

Comment: Can you show what you mean with example code lines?  Does the string contain the `\r` sequence, or `\x0A`, or `\012` or is it a literal carriage return, or something else?  If it is a literal carriage return, the question must be "why"?

Comment: It is a literal carriage string which cannot really be rendered and as I did not write the code, I have no idea why unfortunately.

Comment: I'd look hard at your old language to see whether there is any way to avoid needing the embedded carriage returns in the strings.  Often (but not always) there is a way to include such characters — maybe with an ASCII(13) or some other function call.  If you really can't avoid having them in the original source, then I'd consider whether there is some other character (perhaps ^A, control-A) that does not appear in the source. I'd then consider mapping all ^M (carriage returns) to ^A before passing the code to the C preprocessor, and then map the ^A back to ^M before submitting for compilation.

Comment: Unfortunately changing the source is out of the question.  I guess we are on the same page because I did what you suggested below in pre-pre-processing the code so it would not altered in cpp.  I was really trying to avoid recursively grepping source files for include statements so I can do the pre-pre-process them into a temp directory. Rock - me - Hardplace

Comment: Hmmm. So does this boil down to replacing literal carriage returns that are not immediately followed by line feeds with the two ascii characters '\' and 'r'? `$ perl -pe 's/\r(?!\n)/\\r/g'`.

Answer (score 0):

See `unix2mac`. This is in the *dos2unix* package on cygwin, so probably in a similarly named package on your linux distro.

Comment: Alas this will not do it because it converts it my \x0A into \x0A \x0D